# Symfony2 Persisting form collection with a relational entities

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony

Haven't found a solution to this problem through research yet but I am trying to save into the database with two forms in one (embedded/collection). I have entities that are related to each other and I want the form to submit and persist both entities into the database.

Main entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sub", mappedBy="mainId", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $sub;

public function __construct() {
    $this->sub = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Sub entity:

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="main_id", type="integer")
*/
protected $mainId;

.......

  /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main", inversedBy="sub")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $main;
```

Here's my MainType form:

```
class MainType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dano', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'DA: ',
                'disabled' => true
            ))
        ->add('partno','text', array(
                'label' => 'Part: ',
                'disabled' => true
            ))
        ->add('batchno', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'Batch: ',
                'disabled' => true
            ))
        ->add('sub', 'collection', array('type' => new SubType()))
        ->add('submit', 'submit');
}......
```

And my SubType form:

```
class SubType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('main_id','hidden')
        ->add('rackno','text', array(
                'label' => 'Rack No(s) '
            ))
        ->add('diecode','text', array(
                'label' => 'Die Code '
            ))
        ->add('heatcode','text', array(
                'label' => 'Heat Code '
            ))
        ->add('inqty','integer', array(
                'label' => 'Qty In '
            ))
        ->add('onhold','choice', array(
                'label' => 'Hold',
                'choices' => array(
                    '1' => 'On Hold',
                    '0' => 'Released'
                ),
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true
            ));
```

And my controller:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/{dano}", name="subpart_part")
 */
public function submitPartByDAAction(Request $request, $dano) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Main')
        ->findOneByDano($dano);

    $partno = $entity->getPartno();
    $batchno = $entity->getBatchno();
    $mainid = $entity->getId();


    $main1 = new Main();
    $main1->setDano($dano);
    $main1->setPartno($partno);
    $main1->setBatchno($batchno);

    $sub1 = new Sub();
    $sub1->setMainId($mainid);
    $main1->getSub()->add($sub1);

    $form = $this->createForm(new MainType(), $main1, array(
            'method' => 'POST'
        ));

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($main1);
            $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('subpart_home'));

    }

    return $this->render('Bundle:Parts:addparts.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
}
```

Let me explain what I did here, at first I did not have the Sub's "main_id" field (which is related to Main's id) on but when I tried persisting the data it gave me the error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO sub 
(main_id, rackno, heatcode, diecode, inqty, onhold) VALUES 
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "46", "eterte", "seteter", 3, 0]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 
'main_id' cannot be null
```

So then I made a field "main_id" with it being hidden, grabbed the id from Main by getId(); and passed it into the Sub's form's setMainId(); to persist and it still gives me the same error that "main_id" cannot be null.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining your entities wrong. First understand the concept of ORM and relations. Your `Sub` entity does not need to have the integer `main_id`. Simply map it to `Main` entity. Your  `Main` entity should look like

```
/**
 * @var Sub 
 * this value is just integer in database, but doc should point it to Sub
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sub", mappedBy="mainId", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $sub;

public function __construct() {
    $this->sub = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And your `Sub` entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Main", inversedBy="sub")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="main_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $main;
```

You dont need main_id. The ORM will handle that for you. The `MainType` form is good. Just get rid of the main_id in `SubType` form.

You should reference to entities by object rather than their IDs. In your controller also rather than using

```
$sub1->setMainId($mainid);
```

You should set the object.

```
$sub1->setMain($main1);
```

Comment: also, how can I only persist the datas in Sub entities rather than everything?

Answer (score 1):

Your main form is also a little weird. I do not say it is not valid, but you should consider replacing this line:

->add('sub', 'collection', array('type' => new SubType()))

With something like this:

->add('sub', new SubType(), array())

I think it is way more appropriate if you have only "ONE" item. You use collection when you want many items.

I would suggest you look into the form component... how the form is represented as a tree...

Also never make fields like "main_id", unless it is necessary. Try not to work id's and work with associations.